# Why is the email not saving on user sign up?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-3.0

I went to test the user sign up but it keeps telling me `UNIQUE constraint failed: users_customuser.email`. That's because the email isn't saving with the rest of the form. I checked the database with an inspector and it shows a blank email field. I put a debug print before `form.save` and it showed the username email and password so I know the email is in the form data. The view looks fine so it doesn't make sense to me. Tried switching to django 2.2 and it didn't help. **The form is valid** but the email doesn't save.

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'user_accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter a valid email address')
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
```

signup.html

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `forms.py` to the following

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    # Deleted extra email field
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2') # <-- Added 'email'
```